# Graphical solution of lpp

Tags: linear-programming

I need to solve the following LPP using graphical method

Min $z=-2x_1+x_2$

subject to
$x_1+x_2 \geq 6$,

$3x_1+2x_2 \geq 16$,

$x_2 \leq 9$,

$x_1, x_2 \geq 0$

The common feasible region is unbounded. I am not sure whether the solution is also unbounded or not. In this case I have drawn the line $-2x_1+x_2=2$ and moved it towards the origin as it is a minimisation problem. I am not getting any optimal point. [image]

How can I take decision

Answer (score 0):

In this case, no minimization of the objective function exists, because there is no fixed boundary for increasing values of x1 & x2. Thus, it is not possible to minimize the objective function in this case and so the solution is unbounded.